# Ubuntu 13.04 : no sound

Tags: sound

I have recently installed Ubuntu 13.04,  my headset/earplug isn't working on it, sound is produced only through speakers.

What should I do ? I need to make the earphones work. Thanks.

Here is the output of my alsa-info.sh:

- http://pastebin.com/hSznC2QA

And here is the output of my alsamixer:

[image]

Comment: Paste the output of this script please: http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh

Comment: here it is > http://pastebin.com/hSznC2QA

Comment: What do you see when you type ``alsamixer`` in a terminal; all speakers and headphone controls should be at 100%. The master is your volume control button.

Comment: here it is ->  http://s22.postimg.org/5j4vzv8td/Screenshot_from_2013_07_03_01_38_07.png    IT doesnt show headphone centrols at all.

Comment: try to plug your speakers where you plugged your headphones, and vice versa, is that working? can be hardware related, may be your mother board connectors are with problem on that.

Comment: no this aint hardware related, earplug were working perfectly on windows 8, its just a day back i converted to ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where your pulse audio config is you should try removing it and checking if it automatically reconfigures correctly.

I'm on 13.10 so you'd need to do

```
# cd ~/.config/
# mv pulse/ pulse.bak/
```

Restart your system and Ubuntu will recreate the pulse config. Test and see if it's working now.

This fixed some issues I was having.

Answer (score -1):

Try configuring System Settings ==> Sound ==> Output
choose headphones.

Comment: output is chosen as headphones only